# How to replace a table cell with another cell while preserving the table size

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the following jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/rcCeG/17/

Although it utilizes YUI, the code should be pretty clear:

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y){
    var td = Y.one('#replaceMe'),
        newTd = Y.Node.create('<td><input/></td>'),
        w = td.getDOMNode().getBoundingClientRect().width,
        inputNode = newTd.one('input');

    w -= parseFloat(td.getComputedStyle('paddingLeft')) || 0;
    w -= parseFloat(td.getComputedStyle('paddingRight')) || 0;
    w -= 2 * parseFloat(td.getComputedStyle('borderWidth')) || 0;

    newTd.setStyle('width', w + 'px');
    w -= 2 * parseFloat(inputNode.getComputedStyle('borderWidth')) || 0;
    inputNode.setStyle('width', w + 'px');

    td.replace(newTd);
});​
```

What it does is replaces a cell in the given table with another cell, containing an input box.

Now, I had to perform some width calculations in order for the replacement to preserve the table size. What bothers me especially, is that I had to set the width of the input explicitly, even though it is set to 100% in the CSS:

```
table, td, th {
    border: solid 1px black;
}

table td, table th {
    padding: 2px;
}

input {
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    background-color: #FFFEBB;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If I do not set it, then it looks ugly - the right padding is not respected and I do not understand why.

Please, show me the right way to replace one cell with another while preserving the table size.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the table-cell's width comes from it's children's width. 100% of a width that adjusts to the the width of it's children well... If the input, being a child of td, determines the td's width, what will the 100% do? It won't do nothing... It'll keep the input at it's default size.

Basically, percentage width values inside elements that adjust to it's inner content will be relative to their natural sizes. And another thing: the parent's width will always be equal to the the same natural size of the inner content.

You can see this behavior with floats, as well: jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/gBvn4/

I hope I've made myself clear. I'm in a hurry right now, and can't take the time to clean or better structure the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just explicitly set the width and height of all the cells at once?:

```
table th, table td {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pitaj/rcCeG/13/

Comment: And how do you know it is 25px? And what if it is 23px? or 27px?

Answer (score 0):

try to add `display: block;`

```
input {
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    background-color: #FFFEBB;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

you will need to play with paddings or floating maybe, but generally it should work.